# Problems about Biography part

Tags: wrapfigure

I have two problems with the biography part of my paper. Based on the attached picture:

1) about the blue part, I do not know how to remove the surplus blank space which is colored by blue. I mean, why the picture is lower than the text?!

2) The first bio is finished in red-colored place. The second explanation continued after it! I want to send the second part in front of the second pic. What should I do? I add the codes too:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{25mm} 
\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{Figures/1.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure}\par
\textbf{XXX} received his B.Sc. degree in Telecommunication Engineering from University of XXX, in 2009 and an M.Sc. degree in Information Technology Engineering from Iran University of Science and Technology, in 2012. He is currently a Ph.D. student in the Department of Computer Science at University XXX. His research interests include (but not limited to) network security, cryptography, artificial intelligence, and Blockchain.\par


\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{25mm} 
\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{Figures/2.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure}\par
\textbf{XXX} received his B.S. and M.S. degrees from XXX, and his Ph.D. degree from XXX, all in computer science.  He was a XXX.  He is now a Professor in the Department of Computer and Information Sciences of the University XXX. His research interests include blockchain, Wi-Fi, SDN and NFV, ad hoc and sensor networks, dynamic spectrum management, cybersecurity, distributed computing, and simulation.  He is a recipient of XXX.
```

[image: the mentionded pictuer]